# What are the characteristics of an embedded web server?

Tags: embedded, webserver, embeddedwebserver

How is it different from a webserver running on your desktop?
Does it have different resource consumption requirements? How is it achieved?

E.g. Mongoose web server

http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/

Answer (score 0):

[Embedded HTTP server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_Web_server) article on Wikipedia should answer some of these.